# WPF - CefSharp - show iPhone6 viewport emulation

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I'm using CefSharp.Wpf to make a form with a web Browser inside of it.

What I really want is my preview to show as Google Chrome does like bellow:

[image: DevTools - emulating iPhone6]

I need my preview to shown the dimensions (375 x 667) and make it look like I'm seeing it on the device, just like (Chrome) does when we hit the device button.

Am I able to show this same view in my WPF CefSharp view?

So whatever website I'd open, it'll show me the iPhone6 like version.

What I'm thinking about is to emulate the Devtools of CefSharp and try to set these settings to show the page like that, but I don't know if it's the right path to continue.

Am I able to make it using CefSharp for .Net? 
Does anyone has made something similar and/or could give me a light on it?

Comment: There's an adage in the `CEF` community that goes if you want something like `Google Chrome`, then just use `Google Chrome` ;-). That said, I've posted an answer below.

Comment: You can enable remote debugging and send raw commands to the browser like the devtools interface does. From memory you can use devtools to inspect it's self and see what commands are being sent

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `User-Agent` string to an iOS agent string using `CefSettings`

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A5376e Safari/8536.25
```

Example:

```
CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
settings.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A5376e Safari/8536.25";
Cef.Initialize(settings);
```

If the limitation of only being able to set `CefSettings` once per application is too restrictive, then you can create your own menu of `User-Agent` strings and set them within the `IRequestHandler.OnBeforeResourceLoad` method. see: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CefSharp.Example/RequestHandler.cs#L70 for an example of intercepting the headers.

Comment: is there a way to use chromium or chrome preset? like chrome provides?